# How do I allow a ComboBox to have a selected value that is not in ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a ComboBox like this:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectableValues}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}" />
```

`SelectableValues` is a list of `double` and `SelectedValue` is a `double`. If the user chooses a value from the list or manually enters one of those values, my `SelectedValue` property is updated. But if the user manually enters another value, it isn't. How do I allow `SelectedValue` to take other values than those in `ItemsSource`?

*Edit*: Think of it like the font size box in MS Word. I can choose a value from the list, or provide my own value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743269/editable-combobox-with-binding-to-value-not-in-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a user control inheriting comboBox. Add a dependency property as 'SelectedText'. create event handler for LostFocus on combo box, in event handler assign  the entered value dependency property 'SelectedText'.
do binding on 'SelectedText', in its setter if value is new then ad to collection and set SelectedValue to new one.

Indirectly you have to update source by adding new property in ComboBox.

```
  public class ExtendedComboBox : ComboBox
    {
        public ExtendedComboBox()
        {
            this.IsEditable = true;
            this.LostFocus += ComboBox_LostFocus;
        }
        public string SelectedText
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(SelectedTextProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(SelectedTextProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedText", typeof(string), typeof(ExtendedComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectedTextPropertyChanged)));


        private static void OnSelectedTextPropertyChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ComboBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SelectedText = (e.Source as ComboBox).Text??string.Empty;
        }

    }

   // Binding Example

 %gt%local:ExtendedComboBox Margin="3" x:Name="ecb" SelectedText="{Binding SelectedText,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTextList}">%gt/local:ExtendedComboBox>
```

Comment: I don't actually want to add anything to the list. I want it to work like the font size box in e.g. Word. I can choose one of the values in the list, or I can provide my own value, that will then be used (but not added to the list).

Comment: Ok then in that case dont add value into collection. Anyway you can use it directly. Make sense??

Comment: Basically Combobox has a text property which is not a dependency property. So you have to create a dependency property to extract the enetered text. It can be achieved by subscribing to lostfocus event.