# How to allow a user to type in a combo box

Tags: c#, wpf

Simple question how do you do this http://www.silverlightshow.net/Storage/demos/ComboBoxDemo/ComboBoxDemo.html 
in WPF using c#

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a property in WPF ComboBoxes called `IsEditable`, if you enable this, it effectively becomes a TextBox with the dropdown of a normal ComboBox.  I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: If you are using data binding, there are a few more steps.  See this answer for more details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743269/editable-combobox-with-binding-to-value-not-in-list