# Editable ComboBoxEdit with binding to value not in list

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox, devexpress

I am working with a `ComboBoxEdit` from `DevExpress`.

I have come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743269/editable-combobox-with-binding-to-value-not-in-list) post, where i need the same behavior for my `ComboBoxEdit`. I need the user to be able to type a value in the `ComboBoxEdit`, even though the value is not in the list of bound objects.

This is what i have so far:

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Name="someName"
              Height="Auto" 
              Width="Auto"
              ImmediatePopup="True"
              AutoComplete="True"
              IncrementalFiltering="True"
              IsEnabled="True"
              Visibility="Visible"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              IsTextEditable="True"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
              Mask="###,###,###,##0.00;###,###,###,##0.00-"
              MaskType="Numeric"
              DisplayFormatString="###,###,###,##0.00;###,###,###,##0.00-"
              MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SomeItemsSource}"
              DisplayMember="{Binding Path=SomeDisplayMember}"
              ValueMember="{Binding Path=SomeValueMember}"
              EditValue="{Binding Path=SomeEditValue}">
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
    <dxe:ComboBoxStyleSettings />
</dxe:ComboBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
```

Everything works fine, but i cant type in a value that is not in the list.

**How can i get the same behavior as in the mentioned post for my `ComboBoxEdit`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to set : `ValidateOnTextInput="False"`

Comment: Unfortunately that solution doesn't work right. You can enter a custom text, yes, but if you press enter or klick outside(loose focus) the most similar object from ItemsSource is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

try to use a `"Devexpress.XtraEditors.MRUEdit"`

Comment: You're better to answer by not asking another question, as it might be flagged as "Not an answer".