# DataGrid ComboBox Binding Issue with Selected or New Item

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, combobox

I am having issue with retaining selected item in a DataGridTemplate column ComboBox. 
I have the DataTemplate editable combobox column as the first column in the datagrid and next to it, I have a text column. The DataGrid is populated with data read from SQL stored procedure. Everything works fine, except when I select an item in the combobox and move to the text field and start typing in it, the Combo selection blanks out. It blanks out both for a new item or existing item. Oddly, this happens only the first time. When I reselect the ComboBox Value or add the new item again and go back to the text field, it does not blank out. I am running out of ideas and tried many combinations, but no luck so far.
Here is my code:

This is how I am populating the DataGrid:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "GetProducts";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection = sqlConn;

    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(reader);
    dt.Columns["ProductName"].AllowDBNull = true;
    dtProductCfgTable = dt;
    ProductCfgGrid.ItemsSource = dtProductCfgTable.DefaultView;
}
```

This is the declaration for ProductNamesList:

```
public List<string> ProductNamesList { get; set; }
```

XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ProductName">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ProductNamesList, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"  
                                SelectedItem="{Binding ProductName 
                                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"  
                                BorderThickness="1.2 1.2 0 0" BorderBrush="Black" 
                                Background="LightCyan" IsEditable="True" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>  
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ShippingAddress}" 
                    Width="100" 
                    Header="ShippingAddress" 
                    Visibility="Visible"/>
```

Comment: What have you set your datacontext to?

Comment: I have not set any datacontext for the Grid in this case

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743269/editable-combobox-with-binding-to-value-not-in-list and try those solutions

Comment: tried them, but no luck. It works the same way still

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason the data is lost is because the `CellTemplate` only provides non-edit features, so whenever you changed a value in the combobox when editing a new row, the data wasn't getting set because there was no edit-mode implementation, so no object was getting created behind the scenes. DatagridTextColumn automatically has editing build into it, which is why the combobox would work after editing this type of cell.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ProductName" >
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
                 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ProductNamesList, 
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" 
                 SelectedValue="{Binding ProductName, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
                 IsEditable="False"
                 IsHitTestVisible="False" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ProductNamesList, 
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" 
                 Text="{Binding ProductName, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
                 IsEditable="True" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The redundancy in comboboxes is only necessary if you want the user to see a combobox when in non-edit mode. If you don't care about that you can simply write:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductName}" />
    </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks. However, while this works perfectly for existing items in the combo list, I am not able to add a new item through it. Any ideas ?

Comment: Simply change `SelectedValue` to `Text`. This will cause the Combobox's textbox control to take values not included in the list. Note however that adding your own values won't cause them to enter the list. In order to achieve this functionality you must write an eventhandler for the combobox on something such as `LostFocus`.

Comment: It loses the data again when I change it to SelectedValue. But I am leaving this as the answer since I can do without being able to add new records this point. Thanks for your help

Comment: My vote because of ElementStyle with ItemSource,SelectedValue while EditingElementStyle with ItemSource,Text