# WPF datagrid - Update property after combo item selected

Tags: wpf, datagrid, combobox

I'm new to WPF and have a question about an issue I'm having with a combobox on a datagrid.  When an item is selected from the combo, the bound property does  not update like I expect.

Since I can't post images (this is the first time I've posted to SO), I'll attempt to explain.  If I select "D00120" from the combo list, the combo will reflect the change but the grid property does not get changed.

Xaml:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="CPT Code" Width="75">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PartBCombo, 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" 
                                    DisplayMemberPath="PartBLookup_CPTCode" 
                                    SelectedValuePath="PartBLookup_ProcedureDescription"  
                                    SelectedValue="{Binding PartBBilling_ProcedureName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Property for combo items:

```
    Partial Public Class PartBBilling_Combobox

    Private _PartBLookup_CPTCode As String
    Public Property PartBLookup_CPTCode As String
        Get
            Return _PartBLookup_CPTCode
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _PartBLookup_CPTCode = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _PartBLookup_ProcedureDescription As String
    Public Property PartBLookup_ProcedureDescription As String
        Get
            Return _PartBLookup_ProcedureDescription
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _PartBLookup_ProcedureDescription = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Property for datagrid:

```
    Private _PartBBilling_CPT As String
    Public Property PartBBilling_CPT As String
        Get
            Return _PartBBilling_CPT
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _PartBBilling_CPT = value
            RaisePropertyChanged("PartBBilling_CPT")
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _PartBBilling_ProcedureName As String
    Public Property PartBBilling_ProcedureName As String
        Get
            Return _PartBBilling_ProcedureName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            If _PartBBilling_ProcedureName <> value Then
                _PartBBilling_ProcedureName = value
                RaisePropertyChanged("PartBBilling_ProcedureName")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
```

When an item is selected, the UI displays correctly but the grid property does not get updated.  Other than that, the combobox functions just fine.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0):

First of i think to use something unique for your SelectedValuePath (used for identifying the correct selection)

```
DisplayMemberPath="PartBLookup_CPTCode" 
SelectedValuePath="PartBLookup_CPTCode"
```

Also be careful and note that your SelectedValue will be bound to one of the values inside your PartBCombo collection whatever that type might be. So the Property you bind the SelectedValue to should be of that type.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  If I reverse them, then the procedure name displays in the combo instead of the CPT code (just tried it in case I was missing something).  I want the CPTcode to display and the procedure name displayed in a textbox immediately to the right of the combo.  I can't post an image since I'm new so this is the best way I can explain it.  The property the combo is bound to has to be updated when an item is selected from the combo.  But I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: In order for the selection to work correctly you need to specify something unique like the CTPCode to be your SelectedValuePath

Comment: If I do that then I lose the functionality of displaying the procedure name in the adjacent textbox.  I wish I could post an image to better explain the situation but I need a reputation of at least 10 to post an image.  The combo functionality works as desired.  It's just getting the property in the datagrid class to update correctly.  Otherwise the original selected item in the combo gets written back to the database and not the newly selected item.

Comment: This post explains my problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061176/datagrid-combobox-binding-issue-with-selected-or-new-item  I don't think it's been answered to the op's satisfaction but it is similar to my issue.