# Autocomplete combobox for WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, autocomplete

I need an autocomplete combobox for WPF C#. I've tried several approaches but nothing works. For example I've tried a combobox:

```
<ComboBox  Width="200"
      IsEditable="True"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Names}"
      IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
      HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

`Names` is a List of Strings: Peter John, John, John Doe, Cathy, Howard, John Richards and so on

If you type in a name e.g. John the combobox should expand and I should see

- John
- John Doe
- John Richards
- Peter John

But that doesn't work. How can I do that?

Comment: So far the best solution. But unfortunately it only looks for the first letters in the list. Example: I'm searching for "John" and there is no "Peter John"

Comment: You can config `FilterMode` e.g. use `Contains`

Answer (score 12):

After a lot of fiddling, I have managed to arrive at a complete, working solution. (Or so it seems.)

### Step 1. Modify XAML markup

You need to modify your ComboBox like so:

```
<ComboBox
    ...
    IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
    ...
    PreviewTextInput="PreviewTextInput_EnhanceComboSearch"
    PreviewKeyUp="PreviewKeyUp_EnhanceComboSearch"
    DataObject.Pasting="Pasting_EnhanceComboSearch" />
```

ie. to ***disable*** default text search, and add events handlers that will take care of user adding, deleting and pasting text.

### Step 2. Add a helper function that will get ComboBox's internal TextBox (because WPF)

In order for `PreviewTextInput_EnhanceComboSearch` and `Pasting_EnhanceComboSearch` to work at all, you will need to access your ComboBox's caret. Unfortunately, to do this, you need to traverse, er, visual tree ([hat tip to Matt Hamilton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10279201/5282087)). You can do that in an extension method, but I used a static one in my `Page` class:

```
public static T GetChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj == null) return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

        var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

### Step 3. Implement event handlers

Please note I used

```
s => s.IndexOf(e.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1
```

which is equivalent to case-insensitive `s => s.Contains(e.Text)` check. Remember to change that part to suit your needs.

#### Step 3.a Trigger search on user typing inside ComboBox

When a `PreviewTextInput` handler is run, the `.Text` property inside the ComboBox contains the text from *before* it was modified. Therefore, we need to get ComboBox's internal TextBox using `GetChildOfType` method in order to obtain its caret, so we know where exactly was the typed character inserted.

```
private void PreviewTextInput_EnhanceComboSearch(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;

    cmb.IsDropDownOpen = true;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmb.Text))
    {
        string fullText = cmb.Text.Insert(GetChildOfType<TextBox>(cmb).CaretIndex, e.Text);
        cmb.ItemsSource = Names.Where(s => s.IndexOf(fullText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1).ToList();
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Text))
    {
        cmb.ItemsSource = Names.Where(s => s.IndexOf(e.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        cmb.ItemsSource = Names;
    }
}
```

#### Step 3.b Trigger search on user pasting into ComboBox

`DataObject.Pasting` handler behaves in a similar fashion to `PreviewTextInput` hanlder, so we need the caret again.

```
private void Pasting_EnhanceComboSearch(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;

    cmb.IsDropDownOpen = true;

    string pastedText = (string)e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(string));
    string fullText = cmb.Text.Insert(GetChildOfType<TextBox>(cmb).CaretIndex, pastedText);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullText))
    {
        cmb.ItemsSource = Names.Where(s => s.IndexOf(fullText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        cmb.ItemsSource = Names;
    }
}
```

#### Step 3.c Trigger search on user deleting text inside ComboBox (and also pressing Space, because WPF)

This will trigger when the user depresses either Delete or Backspace.

And also Space, because Space is ignored by `PreviewTextInput`, so it would be difficult to filter out "John" from "John Doe" and "John Richards" in the example.

```
private void PreviewKeyUp_EnhanceComboSearch(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Back || e.Key == Key.Delete)
    {
        ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;

        cmb.IsDropDownOpen = true;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmb.Text))
        {
            cmb.ItemsSource = Names.Where(s => s.IndexOf(cmb.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            cmb.ItemsSource = Names;
        }
    }
}
```

---

...and that should probably be enough.

Comment: Not bad but the entries all go away if you press escape a few times.

Comment: @Chris ...or if you select previously-typed text and type a letter. Yes, there are still more edge cases to cover. I suppose I'll do more research when I have time, but at this point it seems this is indeed the kind of thing for which you need a well-tested library.

Comment: see as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743269/editable-combobox-with-binding-to-value-not-in-list

Comment: I didn't know it was sooooo straight forward :-|

Answer (score 6):

use PreviewTextInput event for do filter and show drop down like this:

```
private void ComboBox_TextInput_1(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {           
        cmbperson.IsDropDownOpen = true;
        cmbperson.ItemsSource = DataBase.Persons.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(e.Text)).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in PreviewTextInput `e.Text` is going to be whatever user has inputted, ie. a single character for keyboards. Also, since this is PreviewTextInput, `ComboBox.Text` is going to be what was in the box *before* the user typed character. However, the note about `IsDropDownOpen` helped me arrive at my solution, so no downvotes from me.

Comment: before text + last thing the user entered!

Comment: nvm it's messy.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use a control made for auto complete instead of a combobox. Many companies offer such controls, [this](https://wpfautocomplete.codeplex.com/) one is free and considered good.

Comment: Thanks Moti but I think your suggestion is not for C#, right?

Comment: @Struct It's for `WPF`, which is works with c#. The control itself is written in `VB.NET` but once it's compiled into a msil it's as good as c# on a library user's account.

Comment: This has a [C# version](https://github.com/quicoli/WPF-AutoComplete-TextBox) now, which is nice if customization is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the implementation that works for me:

```
<ComboBox
    Name="ItemsControl"
    IsEditable="True"
    KeyUp="OnItemsControlKeyUp"
```

I check if the text has changed since the last time the filter was applied (to avoid filtering when a non-alphanumeric key is pressed).

```
private string _textBeforeFilter;

private void OnItemsControlKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var arrowKey = e.Key >= Key.Left && e.Key <= Key.Down;

    // if arrow key (navigating) or the text hasn't changed, then a we don't need to filter
    if (arrowKey || ItemsControl.Text.EqualsIgnoreCase(_textBeforeFilter)) return;

    _textBeforeFilter = ItemsControl.Text;

    var textIsEmpty = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ItemsControl.Text);

    var itemsViewOriginal = (CollectionView) CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ItemsControl.ItemsSource);
    // if the text is empty, then we show everything, otherwise filter based on the text 
    itemsViewOriginal.Filter = o => textIsEmpty || ((string) o).ContainsIgnoreCase(ItemsControl.Text);
}
```

**NOTE:** `EqualsIgnoreCase` and `ContainsIgnoreCase` are extension methods:

```
public static bool EqualsIgnoreCase(this string source, string value)
{
    return source.Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}

public static bool ContainsIgnoreCase(this string source, string value)
{
    return source.Contains(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an autocomplete to `WPF` that could help you.
Follow the link below to github:
https://github.com/rhpontes/AutocompleteWpf

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Please make sure you add enough description of the content before posting a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

In XAML you should set **IsEditable=True** and add handler for PreviewKeyDown event:

```
private void ComboBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
        cmb.IsDropDownOpen = true;
        var textbox = cmb.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", cmb) as TextBox;
        cmb.ItemsSource = CurrentStorage.Organisations.Where(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmb.Text) || p.Name.ToLower().Contains(textbox.Text.ToLower())).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your answer to provide an explanation that will better help people who come here looking for advice on related, but different, problems. See [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more advice.

Answer (score 0):

Use ComboBox.Items.Filter to show items that fits the text written in the textbox. This is an example:

```
            If cmb.Text = "" Then
                cmb.Items.Filter = Nothing
            Else
                Dim T = cmb.Text
                cmb.Items.Filter = Nothing
                Dim I = cmb.Items.IndexOf(T)
                cmb.Items.Filter = Function(x As String)
                                       If x.StartsWith(T) Then Return True
                                       If x.Contains(" " & T) Then Return True
                                       Return False
                                   End Function

                If I = -1 Then
                    cmb.SelectedIndex = -1
                    cmb.Text = T
                    Dim txt As TextBox = cmb.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", cmb)
                    txt.SelectionStart = T.Length
                Else
                    cmb.SelectedIndex = 0
                End If

            End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the link for autocomplete control mentioned in a previous answer is no longer active and in my humble opinion using predefined control is a more viable approach than reinventing your own wheel, here's the [link](https://github.com/quicoli/WPF-AutoComplete-TextBox) for nice control.
You install it as follows

```
Install-Package AutoCompleteTextBox
```

Here's a [demo](https://github.com/quicoli/WPF-AutoComplete-TextBox/tree/develop/AutoCompleteTextBox/SimpleDemo) on how to use it in your code.