# Press an "@" and drop-down a ComboBox. [C#]

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, keypress

First of all sorry if this is repeated, but I didn't find anything yet about that.
Is it possible in C# to press a specific key on a TextBox, in this case "@", and dropdown a list of names?

It's the same thing that FB and Whatsapp does now. In order to save time, if you press @, appears a list of people, and if you continue typing, the list is sorted until you find the name you want.

Comment: [Yes, try using a textbox listener](https://www.dotnetperls.com/textbox-wpf)

Comment: Check autocomeplete text box here : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/autocomplete-textbox-in-wpf/.
You can check for "@" in text change event and load suggestions.

Comment: I think this is what you are asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963022/autocomplete-combobox-for-wpf

You can modify an event to react only on '@'.

Comment: use javascript onchange event and for autocomplete use ajax