# Extended combobox control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, controls

I need a control which extremelly looks like combobox from win `run` window.
My question is is it a standart `combobox control` with specific settings or I have to create a `custom control` in order to achieve this appearance and behavior ?

I'm interested in appearance and behaviour next to the third image - like filtered suggestions which shown as `listbox` in a `popup` after pressing a key.

1. standart combobox

[image: 1. standart combobox]

2. combobox open

[image: 2. combobox open]

3. the most interresting - like filtered suggestions

[image: 3. the most interresting - like filtered suggestions]

---

UPDATED!

Is it a standard combobox control ?
As you can see in the attached gif below when I start inputting something combobox looks like a textbox with popup window under it which contains filtered items. Like a sort of mix between textbox, combobox and popup window with listbox

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autocomplete combobox for WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963022/autocomplete-combobox-for-wpf)

Comment: That's just a standard `ComboBox` with `Editable="True"`. Have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4200216/2029607)

Comment: @XAMlMAX so and when the textbox with filtered items ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are asking for?

Comment: @XAMlMAX I'll update my question right now.

Comment: @Sinatr I'm asking something different

Comment: I can't see the gif or any image for that matter. I am at work behind a proxy. Can you provide more descriptive question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158414/discussion-between-isxaker-and-xamlmax).

Answer (score 1):

This is already built into the `ComboBox`. Here is an example:

```
<ComboBox 
      IsEditable="True" //This enables to enter values that don't belong to the ItemsSource collection
      IsTextSearchEnabled="True" //this allows you to have "suggestions" when you enter text
      IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False" 
      StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
      Text="{Binding NameOnViewModel}"
      TextSearch.TextPath="NameOnChildItems"  //this is the property on which combobox will filter the items
      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" //collection of your items to search on
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}" />//this can be replaced with DisplayMemeberPath="PropertyName"
```

Note:
This example was taken from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743269/editable-combobox-with-binding-to-value-not-in-list/4200216#4200216).
**EDIT**
In case you want the popup to open when you are typing in the values then this could be of help:

```
</ComboBox.Style>  
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">//you can also use a different event if this one doesn't suit your needs.
                <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="true" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Style>
```

**EDIT 2**
For filtering of the VISIBLE objects in the drop down list of your combobox then use the key down event and filter it in the event handler like so:

```
private void cmbKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string temp = ((ComboBox)sender).Text;

    var newList = MyList.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(temp));

    MyList = newList.ToList();
}
```